# DataExtension.Init doesn't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

Good day, friends!
I have created DE in my BU (this is child BU). I can see it, it is available, I can add rows into it. But when I tried to use it in the  script, it returns null rows.
When I try:

```javascript
var testDE = DataExtension.Init("DEname");
var data = testDE.Rows.Retrieve();
if (data.length > 0) {
      Write("The Value " + Stringify(data));
    } else {
      Write("No Rows Found");
    }
```

And it returns "No Rows Found"
What can be the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pasting into `var testDE = DataExtension.Init("...");` Data Extension's **Name**, however you need to paste there **External Key**. So you can either adjust the code to have External Key instead of Name there or make the External Key = Name of the Data Extension.

Read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionFunctions.htm) more.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me!